# Can we use Arithmetic Operators ( + - * / ) in Switch Statement in PHP?

Tags: php, math, switch-statement, operators

I was trying to make a calculator and wanted to use Arithmetic Operators in the switch Statement but i am not able to.

Can someone help me out.

**Error:**

```
Warning: Undefined array key "num2" in on line 16
220

Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in 27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown on line 27
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="php.php" method="post">
Number 1: <input type="number" name="num1"><br>
Operator: <input type="text" name="op"><br>
Number 3: <input type="number" name="num1"><br><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$num1 = $_POST["num1"];
$op = $_POST["op"];
$num2 = $_POST["num2"];
switch($op)
{
    case "+":
        echo $num1 + $num2;
    case "-":
        echo $num1 - $num2;
    case "*":
        echo $num1 * $num2;
    case "/":
        echo $num1 / $num2;         
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"but i am not able to"_ Show your code and the error you get.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Now can you take a look at it! I have put the code

Comment: *"i am not able to"* is not a proper problem description.

Comment: @gre_gor i put the code. Can u please take a look at it.

Comment: "code" is not a problem description.

Comment: You probably want a `break` after each case, but apart from that you still haven't described the problem. What's not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Have you checked what line 16 of your code does? The given error message cannot happen within the `switch` part

Comment: As a hint: why does your form contain two inputs with the **same** name?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="php.php" method="GET">
Number 1: <input type="number" name="num1"><br>
Operator: <input type="text" name="op"><br>
Number 3: <input type="number" name="num2"><br><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$num1 = $_GET['num1'];
$op = $_GET['op'];
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];
    switch($op)
    {
        case '+':
            echo $num1 + $num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            echo $num1 - $num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            echo $num1 * $num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            echo $num1 / $num2;         
            break;
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

1. Put break after every case
2. These was a naming error in the code with the names of the variables. eg num1 and num2. Name them correctly